# UK Standard Visitor Visa: Question Asked At Border for Non-EU (Indian) Citizen

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, borders

I am an Indian citizen, coming to UK on a standard visitor visa. I have a job overseas and have booked both my inbound and outbound air tickets from UK.

Wondering what are the questions that I would be asked at the UK border during immigration. I have searched multiple forums but I have not been able to get any concrete answers.

What I want to understand is:

1. Would I be asked to show my accommodation bookings at the UK border for my entire duration of stay? Would it be okay to book an accommodation for initial couple of days and book further accommodation once I enter?
2. Do I need to show my bank statement at the border for proof of fund available?
3. Any other questions which I may be asked, if any.

I have my rough travel itinerary ready, as to which places I intend to visit as a tourist.

Hope someone can help me answer my these question based on their personal experience.

Comment: What did you state in your visa application regarding your itinerary and accommodation arrangements? You should expect to be asked similar questions to those in the visa application and you should bring a copy of the documents you provided when you applied for your visa with you.

Answer (score 9):

You should expect to be asked similar questions to those in the visa application. It’s a good idea to have with you a copy of the documents you provided when you applied for your visa.

The UK visa application explicitly asks about where you’ll be staying during your visit. Plans do of course change, however if the accommodation details you gave when you applied are materially different (for example, you said you’d be staying in hotels but are now planning to stay with family/friends instead) you should be prepared to explain the change in case you are asked.

Answer (score 5):

I recently entered the UK. I kept these documents in file.

1. Passport, with UK Visa.
2. Invitation letter (Proof of accommodation).
3. Return ticket
4. Vaccination proof

I approached (as a family, together) to immigration officer and we both gave the passport. He checked the passport and asked the following.

1. Purpose of visit
2. Where are you staying?
3. How many days are you here in UK?
4. When are you returning?

He was satisfied with the answers and stamped the passports. No exit checks for UK, so that was it.

In addition to above documents, proof of funds (bank statements), marriage certificate (copy, if your spouse accompanies), would also be good. Do not bring prints of documents such as resume, academic certificates and all, as they will think that you are here to overstay (they may decide to search your bags if they are suspicious). Other documents proving your net worth or any other to prove ties to your home country is not needed.

For us, the stay was only for a week and our background was strong. We didn't change any plans as shown in visa application.